# Modal closing when clicking outside it - needs to call same function as when clicked on close modal button in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-forms, angular2-directives

Modal gets closed when clicked on the close modal button as well as when mouse clicked outside the modal
I want to call the same function that I call when I click on the close modal button also when I click outside the modal. I am not sure how to do this in Angular 2. Could you please share your ideas on this. 
Also my Modal is a part of my main html and it doesnot have a separate component or html...
Thanks

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgModule, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';
import * as jQuery from 'jquery';

export class Component implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('newModal') newModal: ElementRef; 

public OpenModal(){
jQuery(this.newModal.nativeElement).modal('show');
}
public CloseModal(){
Includes actions taken when close modal button is clicked - I want the same function to be called with I click outside the model
}        
}
```

I tried the below in html but this is running whenever I click anywhere on the component other than the modal area.

```
(clickOutside)="CloseModal()";
```

Comment: See this:https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: What are you using to create the modal, bootstrap?  Some angular library?  You would need to hook into whatever event happens and call the same code.

Comment: Hi Jason I have updated my question with more details Please review it and share your inputs

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I solved it by adding a function for clicking outside the native element and change in some of the conditions and it worked for me....

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's, according to what modal you use, pretty easy. Normally each modal dialogue has an onDismiss()-Observable to wich you can subscribe. To make sure that it has been instantiated already perform your subscription inside AfterViewInit.

```
ngAfterViewInit() {

  // react on modal closed by clicking beside it
  this.newModal.onDismiss.subscribe(() => {
    // here goes your code then
  });

}
```

That works perfect for me all the time.

Comment: Hi DiabolicWords  I am new to Angular I tried using ngAfterViewInit in the way you mentioned but I am getting error saying "Cannot read property 'subscribe' of undefined" I am not sure what should I subscribe this to.   ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.newModal.onDismiss.subscribe(() => {
      this.CloseModal();
    });
    console.log("ngAfterViewInit");
  }

Comment: Oh I see. Well I'm actually using a ModalComponent and am not experienced when it comes to handle a modal via jQuery. Sorry! Maybe this works, but is just hipshooting: 

ngAfterViewInit() { jQuery(this.newModal.nativeElement).modal('onDismiss').subscribe(() => {
    // here goes your code then
  }); }

Comment: That doesn't work for me as my Modal is a part of my html and it doesnot have a separate component do you know of any other lifecycle hook that could work the same way for an internal child modal?

Comment: I subscribed to `onDismiss` event in ngAfterViewInit and it works like a charm!. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using NgbModel

```
import { NgbModal, ModalDismissReasons } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
```

then call its inside constructor like this:

```
constructor(private modalService: NgbModal)
```

and call its own method:

```
this.modalService.dismissAll();
```

no need to pass any argument